# WPF: OnRender and Hit Testing

Tags: wpf, hittest

when using OnRender to draw something on the screen, is there any way to perform Hit Testing on the drawn graphics?

Sample Code

```
    protected override void OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);

        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Black, null, new Rect(50, 50, 100, 100));
    }
```

Obviously one has no reference to the drawn Rectangle which would be necessary to perform hit testing or am I wrong about this? I know I can use DrawingVisual, I'm just curious if my understanding is correct, that using OnRender to draw something you can't perform any hit testing on the drawn things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You understood right, there is no way do hittesting on the graphics you have drawn using the DrawingContext methods because they are not represented as objects in the visual tree.

Comment: Sorry unless I'm misunderstanding the OP's question this is not correct.

Comment: The OP wants know know wether his mouse hit the rectangle he was drawing using `DrawingContext` or something else, for example a circle he was drawing using `DrawingContext`. So, you found a way how to do it?

Comment: But he's not drawing a circle using DrawingContext. He's only drawing one thing - the rectangle. As long as that's the only thing he's drawing then the hit test will tell him whether he hit the rectangle. Specifically he asked if it's true that "using OnRender to draw something you can't perform any hit testing on the drawn things?" And that's not true. What is true is that you can't distinguish between two drawing ops done in the same OnRender, but that's a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm completely misunderstanding the OP's question, the answer is YES the hit test is based on what's drawn during `OnRender`. You can tell by overriding `OnMouseEnter` in the same class in which you override `OnRender`. In the override  of `OnMouseEnter` try this:

```
var htr = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, e.GetPosition(this));
if (htr != null)
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("It's a hit!");
```

Now, I notice you're still calling `base.OnRender` which suggests you are trying to draw ON TOP of what the `Visual` would otherwise render. What you won't be able to do, then, is distinguish a hit on what the parent class rendered from what you rendered in your override. However if you need that, just keep your drawing contained to its own `Visual`.

Comment: You have no way of knowing wether you hit the rectangle, because it is not a UIElement. The hit test will just return the control he used to draw on using `OnRender` but not the graphics that werde drawn using the `DrawingContex`.

Answer (score -1):

My quick solution. Its not ideal in many ways but it works for me as a start. Can easily be refactored for performance if that becomes necessary.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides basic hit testing
    /// </summary>
    public class RadarHitTestUtility
    {
        public Dictionary<Tuple<int,int>, HitContainer> HitStorage = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, HitContainer>();

        public void AddEllipse(RadarObject radarObject, Point point, double x, double y)
        {
            // Geometry used for hit testing
            var elipse = new EllipseGeometry
            {
                Center = point,
                RadiusX = x,
                RadiusY = y,
            };

            var key = new Tuple<int, int>((int)point.X, (int)point.Y);

            var hit = new HitContainer
            {
                Geometry = elipse,
                Bounds = elipse.Bounds,
                RadarObject = radarObject
            };

            if(!HitStorage.ContainsKey(key))
                HitStorage.Add(key, hit);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets first radar object whose center point is within distance of point.
        /// </summary>
        public HitContainer GetSimpleHit(Point point, int distance = 5)
        {
            foreach (var hit in HitStorage)
            {
                if (Math.Abs(hit.Key.Item1 - point.X) <= distance && Math.Abs(hit.Key.Item2 - point.Y) <= distance)
                {
                    hit.Value.Intersection = IntersectionDetail.NotCalculated;
                    return hit.Value;
                }
            }
            return default(HitContainer);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets first radar object that contains point
        /// </summary>
        public HitContainer GetHit(Point point)
        {
            var PreCheckDistance = 50;

            foreach (var hit in HitStorage)
            {
                if (Math.Abs(hit.Key.Item1 - point.X) <= PreCheckDistance && Math.Abs(hit.Key.Item2 - point.Y) <= PreCheckDistance)
                {
                    if (hit.Value.Geometry.FillContains(point))
                    {
                        hit.Value.Intersection = IntersectionDetail.FullyInside;
                        return hit.Value;
                    }                    
                }
            }
            return default(HitContainer);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets first radar object that intersects with geometry
        /// </summary>
        public HitContainer GetHit(Geometry geometry)
        {
            var PreCheckDistance = 50;
            var GeometryCheckTolerance = 1;
            var center = geometry.Bounds.Center();

            foreach (var hit in HitStorage)
            {
                if (Math.Abs(hit.Key.Item1 - center.X) <= PreCheckDistance && Math.Abs(hit.Key.Item2 - center.Y) <= PreCheckDistance)
                {
                    var result = hit.Value.Geometry.FillContainsWithDetail(geometry, GeometryCheckTolerance, ToleranceType.Absolute);
                    if (result != IntersectionDetail.Empty)
                    {
                        hit.Value.Intersection = result;
                        return hit.Value;
                    }
                }
            }
            return default(HitContainer);
        }

        public class HitContainer
        {
            public RadarObject RadarObject { get; set; }
            public Geometry Geometry { get; set; }
            public Rect Bounds { get; set; }
            public IntersectionDetail Intersection { get; set; }
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            HitStorage.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Declare an instance in your control

```
public RadarHitTestUtility HitTester = new RadarHitTestUtility();
```

You'll need to call Clear() at some point so that only current objects exist in the hit test collection.

```
HitTester.Clear();
```

In OnRender() when you want a draw call to be recorded for hit testing purposes you can record it with AddEllipse()

```
HitTester.AddEllipse(radarObject, radarObject.Point, actorRadius, actorRadius);
```

Here's how i am calling for the hit check

```
    private void MouseDownHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        IsMouseDown = true;
        Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        DragInitialPosition = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
        DragInitialPanOffset = CanvasData.PanOffset;

        var hit = FindElementUnderClick(sender, e);
        if (hit != null)
        {
            SelectedItem = hit.RadarObject.Actor;
        }            
    }

    private RadarHitTestUtility.HitContainer FindElementUnderClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var position = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);            
        return HitTester.GetHit(position);
    }
```

If you want to be able to test shapes other than an ellipse you would just add the appropriate recording method into RadarHitTestUtility and call it, creating a different kind of Geometry to test against.